# Data trigger work with TextBox but doesnt work with TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have some `DatTrigger`s which set text color for `ListView` items. If I use `TextBox` as `ItemTemplate` for the `ListView` it works perfectly. But it doesn't work if I use `TextBlock`.

This code:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level,Mode=OneWay}"
                     Value="{x:Static Common:LoggingLevel.Error}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level,Mode=OneWay}"
                     Value="{x:Static Common:LoggingLevel.Warning}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Orange" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

...

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Text,Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

produces properly colored list of messages.

While this code:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level,Mode=OneWay}"
                     Value="{x:Static Common:LoggingLevel.Error}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level,Mode=OneWay}"
                     Value="{x:Static Common:LoggingLevel.Warning}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Orange" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

...

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text,Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

renders all messages with default black foreground color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implicit styles are applied within templates to elements which inherit from `System.Windows.Controls.Control` and since `TextBlock` inherits directly from `FrameworkElement` it will not apply. To make it work you must give your `Style` `x:Key` and assign style explicitly to your `TextBlock` or define your style within `TextBlock`
**UPDATE:**
I should also mention, to cover the topic, that there is a way to apply implicit `Style` to all `TextBlocks`. If you put it in `Application.Resources` it will apply to all `TextBlocks` across whole application. In this case it would cause some major performance issues and potentially other errors, which is probably why Microsoft decided to protect these basic elements from accidentally using complicated, implicit styles on them. Not everyone realise that basically every piece of text that you see in your `Window` ends up as `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the key to the `Style` and apply it with the `TextBlock` as shown below:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="txtID">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level,Mode=OneWay}" Value="{x:Static Common:LoggingLevel.Error}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level,Mode=OneWay}" Value="{x:StaticCommon:LoggingLevel.Warning}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text,Mode=OneWay}" Style="{DynamicResource txtID}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```